# Extra 'fingers' found in graph after applying FFT in MATLAB

Tags: fft, matlab

I am currently working on the FFT function in MATLAB. In this function, i require a 1024 number of data Time Domain plot and produce a 400 number of data Frequency domain plot.

After applying the FFT function, i obtain a result of a graph going up to 6000Hz.

However, the Frequency band produced is too big and I only wanna analyze between 0 ~ 500 Hz.
I applied the Chirp-Z transform to obtain the band of 0 ~ 500 Hz, at the same time retaining the output as 400 number of data. This is what I obtain:

[image]

The problem arise as I made a comparison to the graph originally in Frequency Domain already.

[image]

(Please note that I have already both the original graphs - Time and Frequency domain to make comparison with)

As I compared the graph from MATLAB and the original one, there seems to be extra 'fingers' or so present when its supposed to be a straight line. What could be the problem and its appropriate solution?

***EDIT 1***

After trying almost all available Window functions, the taylorwin Window function seems the best and this is the result:

[image]

However it still does not produce a graph that is almost similar to the original graph

Comment: Are you applying a suitable window function prior to the FFT ?

Comment: @PaulR I'm using this function from MATLAB - Chirp Z-Transform
http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/czt.html

Comment: OK - but are you applying a suitable window function prior to the FFT ?

Comment: I think its just a regular rectangular window function.. or maybe not. Still a little unsure about this.

Comment: If you're not explicitly applying a [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) prior to the FFT then you have an implicit rectangular window function and you will get [spectral leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage) in the general case.

Comment: Oh okay.. so am I more advised in this case to apply a window? If yes, which window function should i choose as there are quite a handful

Comment: It depends on your requirements for sharpness of peaks, amplitude of sidelobes, etc, but either a von Hann or Hamming window would probably be a good all round choice. You may need to experiment.

Comment: Ohhh okay! :) thanks @PaulR.. I've tied those two functions, but still not getting closer to the original image =\

Comment: Added a result when a Window function is applied, but still not very similar to the original graph.. :(

Comment: Is the red graph the FFT output?  It seems like you've used lots more data to generate the red / black graph than what you are displaying in the blue / white graphs (windowed or unwindowed).

Comment: @PeterK. Yeah if im not wrong the red graph has much more data, but its collected directly from the analyzer. However I was hoping to achieve a more accurate FFT output graph from MATLAB despite being only 400 number of datas

Comment: Is it possible to get several lots of the 1024-sized time-domain data that you are using for matlab?  The only way to get better resolution with the FFT (or CZT) is to get more data.  Another approach you might try is something like [`pyulear`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pyulear.html), which does a "high resolution" (AR) spectrum... however, it probably is not quite what you're after.

Comment: Do you mean other sets of graphs with 1024-sized time-domain data, or a set with more than 1024 data in it?

Comment: Either a set with more than 1024 data points in it, or more than one set of 1024 data points.  The first would be easier, but the second can also be used to form a PSD with better resolution.